# Lock in while loop condition not working

Tags: c#

Two thread accessing same static variable in different class.

```
        public void decrementCounter()
    {
        while (CounterClass.Counter > 0)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                counterClass.RemoveValuesFromCounter(decrementRate);
                ItemsRemovedFromCounter += decrementRate;
                if(CounterClass.Counter<= decrementRate)
                {
                    decrementRate = CounterClass.Counter;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($" Items Removed by  Counter {ProcessCounterID} : {ItemsRemovedFromCounter}");
            }
        }
    }

public class CounterClass
{
    public static int Counter { get; private set; }
    public CounterClass(int counter)
    {
        Counter = counter;
    }

    public void RemoveValuesFromCounter(int val)
    {
        Counter -= val;
    }
}
```

when i create n number of threads, each thread runs decrementCounter() method and decrements value of counter in counter class until its zero. I put a lock to avoid same thread accessing at the same time, but its not working.

Comment: *"but its not working."* - define "not working". What does it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Also, `lock(this)` is [bad practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement#remarks). You should have a `private` object for locking that can't be accessed anywhere else. You should probably also have all the locking happening in `CounterClass` rather than wherever the `decrementCounter` method lives.

Comment: Your lock object should be a public static variable (just declare an instance of Object for this purpose) that all threads are using.

Comment: Will try to explain this(sorry not good in explaining) e.g. Thread1 enters (while (CounterClass.Counter > 0)  but another thread, Thread2 decrements the counter to zero. so how to avoid this type of situation. Also i am new to multi thread programming

Comment: If all you're doing is maintaining a counter (nothing more intricate based on the counter's value), [`Interlocked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.interlocked) is your friend.

Comment: First of all, you don't synchronize static state with instance context.  Add a readonly private static object sync = new object() somewhere and lock on it instead of this.

Comment: You need to double check, because both threads could try to set the lock at the same time.  One will get it, the other will wait.  Inside the lock, you need to check if `Counter > 0` again.  Another option might be to put the lock outside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have a separate instance of the class containing `decrementCounter` for each thread, your lock does absolutely nothing because each thread has its own separate lock.  You need to share a single lock object between all threads (and it should be a lock object that nothing else can get access to so nothing else can accidentally or intentionally acquire the lock).

But assuming you fix that and the lock is shared between all threads you have another problem:

Your lock only stops multiple threads from decrementing the counter simultaneously.  It doesn't stop them from simultaneously checking its value as the while loop condition.

Here's what could happen:

Thread 1 accesses `CounterClass.Counter`.  Let's say it sees the value `1`.  So it enters the while loop body and enters the lock section and goes to sleep (`Thread.Sleep`).

Thread 2 accesses `CounterClass.Counter`.  It sees the value `1` because nothing has changed yet.  It enters the while loop body and then blocks at the lock waiting for thread 1 to leave.

Thread 1 wakes up, decrements the counter (and does all that other work).  Let's say the counter is now 0.  Thread 1 leaves the `lock` section.

Thread 2 can now enter the `lock` section, so it does.  It decrements the counter (and does all the other work).  The counter is now -1.  Thread 2 leaves the `lock` section.

You need to move the access of the `CounterClass.Counter` property inside the lock.

But then this will defeat the entire purpose of using separate threads, because only one thread is actually doing anything at a given time while all the remaining threads are waiting to enter that critical section.

Without knowing more about what you're trying to do it's not possible to say how to fix it.